# Description list using package enumitem: how to force lowercase small caps and align body text?

Tags: lists, small-caps, enumitem, capitalization, description

I'm trying to format a description list with small caps for the labels and have the body text a standard distance from the left margin. When I use capitals in the labels (in the real list they are abbreviations and acronyms) and try to force lowercase and then small caps, I only get the first letter in small caps. Also, the "leftmargin" option seems only to apply if there is a second line (i.e., like a hanging indent). I'd like all the body text to be indented the same amount from the left margin, regardless of the size of the label.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}   
\usepackage{enumitem}   

\begin{document}   

\begin{description}[leftmargin=4cm,font=\normalfont\scshape\MakeLowercase]   
   \item[FIRST] My definition here   
   \item[NEXT] and another one   
   \item[AFTER] This is the third   
\end{description}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that `\MakeLowerCase` works like `\textsc{}` not like `\scshape` i.e. it needs an argument, so can't be used like a font declaration.

Comment: [A possibly relevant link](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=casechange)

Answer (score 4):

To change to lowercase case, you can use the `before=...` key of [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to redefine `\makelabel` in order to apply `\MakeLowercase` to the whole label text:

```
\newcommand{\descriptionmakelabel}[1]{\scshape\MakeLowercase{#1}}
\begin{description}[before=\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\descriptionmakelabel}]
```

To set the leftmargin automatically to the largest description label, you can use the package [eqparbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) which allows to make all boxes sharing a same label the same width (requires two compilations). You need of course to make the eqparbox label unique to a particular description, which may be done with a counter. Here's the full code with its result:

[image: result of the code]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcounter{desc}
\newcommand{\descriptionmakelabel}[1]{\eqparbox{descnb\romannumeral\value{desc}}{\scshape\MakeLowercase{#1}\hfill}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[before=\refstepcounter{desc}\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\descriptionmakelabel},leftmargin=\eqboxwidth{descnb\romannumeral\numexpr\value{desc}+1\relax}]
   \item[FIRST] My definition here
   \item[NEXT] and another one   
   \item[AFTER] This is the third which is very very very very very very very very very very very very very long
\end{description}

\begin{description}[before=\refstepcounter{desc}\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\descriptionmakelabel},leftmargin=\eqboxwidth{descnb\romannumeral\numexpr\value{desc}+1\relax}]
   \item[A] a short text
   \item[B] a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

use a tabular, it makes more sense here:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}   
\usepackage{tabularx}   
\def\MyLowercase!#1!{\scshape\MakeLowercase{#1}}
\begin{document}   

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\MyLowercase!}p{4cm}<{!}X@{}}   
  FIRST & My definition here\\   
  NEXT  & and another one  and the line can be long as you like it
           there will be a linebreak if needed \\
  AFTER & This is the third   \\
\end{tabularx}   

\end{document}
```