# Lower case of the small caps in description

Tags: lists, small-caps, capitalization, description, classicthesis

I would to use the normal small caps with the item in `description` in order to distinguish lower from upper case (e.g. LaTeX).

In particular:

```
\begin{description}
\item[I cAn't DiStiNguISH upPeR fROm LoWeR cASe] description1
\item[AlSo HeRe] description2
\end{description}
```

I would something like the normal small caps `\textsc{YeS I LiKe It!}`

I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10058/description-list-using-package-enumitem-how-to-force-lowercase-small-caps-and-a) but it doesn't help me.

Edit: I use the package `classicthesis`

Comment: With [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), @lockstep's answer produces the default small caps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[font=\normalfont\scshape]
\item[I cAn't DiStiNguISH upPeR fROm LoWeR cASe] description1
\item[AlSo HeRe] description2
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Here's a solution for `classicthesis`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

% \renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}% OLD
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}\textsc{#1}}% NEW

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[I cAn't DiStiNguISH upPeR fROm LoWeR cASe] description1
\item[AlSo HeRe] description2
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works. Can I also modify the font size?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}\large\textsc{#1}}`

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use `\small` =)